# Is eager loading same as join fetch?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, orm, activerecord

Is eager fetch same as join fetch?

I mean whether eagerly fetching a has-many relation fires 2 queries or a single join query?

How does rails active record implement a join fetch of associations as it doesnt know the table's meta-data in first hand (I mean columns in the table)? Say for example i have

people - id, name
things - id, person_id, name

person has one-to-many relation with the things. So how does it generate the query with all the column aliases even though it cannot know it when i do a join fetch on people?

Comment: and "includes" is similar to a join fetch in jpa/hibernate

Comment: Hibernate has both eager fetch and join fetch. Is there a difference between them?

Comment: (has been a while since hibernate but I think)  "eager fetch" means you are telling Hibernate to "load the object instances into memory right now", a "join fetch" is a shortcut (just like "includes") that allows you to define in a single query/sentence that you want multi-level associations to also be joined and fetched when returned.  In ActiveRecord an "eager join fetch" would be: 'People.includes(:things).all'    (the 'all' pulls them into memory now, instead of waiting for them to be iterated over.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer hasn't been accepted so I will try to answer your questions as I understand them:

- "how does it know all the fields available in a table?"

It does a SQL query for every class that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base.  If the class is 'Dog', it will do a query to find the column names of the table 'dogs'.  In production mode it should only do this query once per run of the server -- in development mode it does it a lot.  The query will differ depending on the database you use, and it is usually an expensive query.

- "Say if i have a same name for column in a table and in an associated table how does it resolve this?"

If you are doing a join, it generates sql using the table names as prefixes to avoid ambiguities.  In fact, if you are doing a join in Rails and want to add a condition (using custom SQL) for name, but both the main table and join table have a name column, you need to specify the table name in your sql.  (e.g. Human.join(:pets).where("humans.name = 'John'"))

- "I mean whether eagerly fetching a has-many relation fires 2 queries or a single join query?"

Different Rails versions are different.  I *think* that early versions did a single join query at all times.  Later versions would sometimes do multiple queries and sometimes a single join query, based on the realization that a single join query isn't always as performant as multiple queries.  I'm not sure of the exact logic that it uses to decide.  Recently, in Rails 3, I am seeing multiple queries happening in my current codebase -- but maybe it sometimes does a join as well, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It knows the columns through a type of reflection.  Ruby is very flexible and allows you to build functionality that will be used/defined during runtime and doesn't need to be stated ahead of time.  It learns the associated "person_id" column by interpreting the "belongs_to :person" and knowing that "person_id" is the field that would be associated and the table would be called "people".

If you do People.includes(:things) then it will generate 2 queries, 1 that gets the people and a second that gets the things that have a relation to the people that exist.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: It can know about the fields in class but what i am asking is how does it know all the fields available in a table. Say if i have a same name for column in a table and in an associated table how does it resolve this? How does it even know there is a ambiguity in first place

Comment: It knows about the fields in the class yes (just like java) but it also uses reflection to interrogate the data model behind the class (if it inherits from ActiveRecord::Base) and stores that column data in another data structure in the class, now called "arel_table".  Arel is the relational algebra package that actually compiles queries (a little bit like HQL, since you are familiar with Hibernate).  For the ambiguity, this is resolved because each "arel_table" behind the scenes tracks it's own scope and resolves relations within it based on the relationship you define (has_many has_one ...)